# GtkSourceView and Mono, c# - example not working, lack of documentation

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I tried to compile a example from Mono website:
http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtkSourceView.SourceView

I tried to use this command:

```
mcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0,gtksourceview2-sharp task3.cs
```

I've got a errors:

> task3.cs(17,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SourceLanguagesManager' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>   task3.cs(20,29): error CS0841: A local variable`manager' cannot be used before it is declared
>   task3.cs(24,10): error CS1061: Type `GtkSourceView.SourceBuffer' does not contain a definition for`Highlight' and no extension method `Highlight' of type`GtkSourceView.SourceBuffer' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

How to compile this example on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Do you have `https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/libgtksourceview2-2.0-cil` installed? Looks like the reference to `gtksourceview2-sharp` does not work and therefore `SourceLanguagesManager` is not found. What release of `mono` are you using (2.x/3.x)?

Comment: Yes, acording to `dpkg -l | grep libgtksourceview2` I have on my machine following packages: 
libgtksourceview2-2.0-cil
libgtksourceview2-cil-dev
libgtksourceview2.0-0
libgtksourceview2.0-common
libgtksourceview2.0-dev.    My Mono version is `Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)`.